# How to rectify the error in payu payment gateway in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

[image]

In one of my website, I have integrated payu payment gateway,after all the debit card details in the payu page,it is going to this page instead of showing the page where we enter otp which shows an error as shown in the image above.

Is this an error in the part of the payment gateway or coding mistake ?

Comment: Anyone here to suggest me a solution ?

Comment: As the error clear say its from payment gateway problem. if it redirects to mentioned page